# Outlook 2016 Skype Plugin

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, skype-for-business

I am dealing with a couple of laptops where the Skype for business plugin for Outlook has stopped responding completely.

When the plugin is removed it can't be added again.

I've tried opening the addin from the original location and also installing the addin manually from a download.

I've also tried running a repair on Office and Outlook/Skype separately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the steps in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0e6ca8b-978a-4141-b94e-319332c31008/skype-for-business-meeting-addin-in-outlook-disappears-when-restarting-outlook?forum=outlook) to delete the value under DisabledItems and CrashingAddinList keys in case this add-in is disabled.

When adding the add-in back, are there any errors? You may replace the add-in file with one from another computer (without problems) to see if it works.

If none of this helps, try reinstalling Skype